# window.open() in <asp:Hyperlink> in GridView passing id

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using `<asp:HyperLink>` in `Gridview`

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/zoom.png" OnClick="javascript:window.open('ProductSummary.aspx?id=', 'open_window', 'width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I need to know that how to pass `'<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'` in query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to produce the entire OnClick event in the DataSource for the grid view, and bind to that:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/zoom.png"
    OnClick='<%# Eval("PopupClickEvent") %>' ... />
```

Otherwise, it should still be possible to have

```
OnClick='<%# Eval("ProductID", "javascript:window.open('ProductSummary.aspx?id={0}', ...)") %>'
```

But the quotation escaping gets messy and confusing very quickly.

For reference, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)